# GPU crash, possible power issue?

Tags: power-supply, crash, gpu, power

I am having trouble with my new GPU, and I think it's a power issue.
**The setup:** PSU Mars Gaming MPII 550, CPU i5-10400
**The problem:** I installed yesterday, for the first time, my GPU GTX 970. The PSU doesn't have the necessary power cables (2x6pin), so I used adapters: 2x4pin-to-6pin, and SATA-to-6pin. The PC turns on, performs basic tasks and plays old games, but reboots when under stress (opening a newer game or performing an UserBenchmark test).
**The question:** Could a more powerful PSU, with the necessary 2x6pin power cables, solve my problem? If not, what do you recommend trying?

Comment: Windows must be generating a mini dump when it automatically reboots, and if it’s not, you need enable that option so that happens, otherwise you cannot properly diagnose the issue you describe

Comment: @Ramhound It's possible that I'm not checking properly, but I can't find any dump file in C:\Windows\Minidump, and in Advanced System Settings I have "generate small dump file (256 KB)" marked. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: When the computer reboots, does the monitor show anything (i.e. BSOD, etc.) before fully shutting down, or does the monitor go directly to black as if you had unplugged the power cable to the computer itself. Also, does there happen to be a single audible click noise coming from the PSU at the moment the computer shuts down? The noise would be rather quiet if present.

Comment: @Next-DoorTech Nothing, no BSOD, no sound. BUT! I changed PSU and now the problem is solved. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti Glad you got it solved! Go ahead and leave the question up so other folks who have a similar question in the future might find this helpful.

Comment: @MauroGiliberti In case you were wondering, no BSOD (straight to black/no signal) on an unexpected shutdown is a pretty strong indicator that the issue is likely caused by power loss to the machine. If present, the clicking sound would be from a shutoff relay in the PSU (a relay is basically a physical switch which is turned on or off by a small electromagnet). Not all power supplies will use a relay, so no sound doesn't necessarily mean something in particular. If there *is* a sound it would be from the PSU shutting off power due to overheating/too much current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Next-DoorTech suggested, I will leave the question up, but I found the issue: it was the PSU. I bought a new PSU (better known brand, slightly more power, and without the necessity for adapters) and everything is going smoothly now.